# Facebook OAuth (FBOAuth) fails to login

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization, social-network

I've installed the [Facebook OAuth module](http://drupal.org/project/fboauth) which is an essential part of the website I am building. Unfortunately, the connection fails:

> "The Facebook login could not be completed due to an error. Please create an account or contact us directly. Details about this error have already been recorded to the error log."

The module seems to perform just fine in the beginning. Once I click on the FConnect button, I am redirected to facebook website, asked to login and grant access to precisely that information which I asked for when configuring the module.

(Also, when I misconfigure the facebook app, for instance by entering the wrong site domain, I am blocked much further in the process.)

The problem occurs when I am sent back from facebook to my website. Then instead of being connected, I receive the error message I mentioned.

I have had a valuable exchange with the maintainer of the module that can be found on http://drupal.org/node/1994900#comment-7419898. Unfortunately, he could not figure out the problem.

I have spent two days on it, trying many different things, but I could not find a solution. You can find a complete record of my different attempts on http://drupal.org/node/1994900#comment-7419898, but to summarize I have:

- checked solutions proposed in related issues, http://drupal.org/node/1441978, http://drupal.org/node/1466598, 
  http://drupal.org/node/1974488.
- Tried with and without clean url's
- Tried to disable absolutely all the modules except for fb oauth to check whether it was a module compatibility issue (also tried a clear install of drupal with only Facebook Oauth module)
- Checked that http requests were enables on my server.
- Tried the alternative Fbconnect module, but I could not configure it either (I got unsolvable errors message before I could even try a connection).

Now I am short of ideas... Anything to propose?

I must say that **I am a beginner**, so I do not get most technical details. **My sepcs** are:

- Drupal 7.22
- Facebook OAuth 7.x-1.6
- Hosted by Host1Free.

Answer (score 1):

For its functionality you need to follow these steps:

1. Make an Application on Facebook.
2. Visit https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and create a new application.
3. While making the application on Facebook don't forget to disable the Sandbox Mode.
4. Add a Website domain name on which you want to use the fboauth login button.
5. From there copy the  App. ID and App Secret to **/admin/config/people/fboauth**

That would work for you.

Comment: @ Nitesh Sethia : Thanks for you answer. Unfortunately I gave on this application cause I really could not make it work and it took me too much time. I do not plan to resume this project soon, but if I do, I will see if applying your procedure, see if it makes a difference, and I'll come back to you.

Comment: @MartinVanderLinden Would be happy to help.